# Form reloading in C#.net

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form i am fetching many records from database that are rendering dynamical on from. When i am clicking on Delete button this is deleting as well but I want to re-render my form so user will feel that records is deleted completely. when i am writing code this.refresh(); this is not fetching values from database and i am not seeing record is completely gone. It is windows C# form.

Comment: What kind of form is this: Webform, Winform, or other?  There are different kinds of forms here and this is an important point for anyone to really help you unless you want answers for all cases which I'd kind of doubt.

Comment: sorry to mention .... It is Winform

Comment: DatagridName.Databind()?

Comment: Nothing using with datagrid and databind. Just simple fetching values when constructor is calling and rendring on form with co-ordinate system positioning with record name and delete button with each record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The methods `Form.Refresh` and `Form.Invalidate` have nothing to do with causing the application to retrieve new data from the database.

- `Form.Refresh` - redraws the form synchronously (i.e. `Form.OnPaintBackground` and `Form.OnPaint` are called directly on the current thread).
- `Form.Invalidate` - redraws the form asynchronously (i.e. `WM_PAINT` message is sent to the window, so `Form.OnPaintBackground` and `Form.OnPaint` will be called by the UI thread when it handles messages).

In order to update records, you need to make your control retrieve updated data.

If you specify more details on how the `Form` pulls that data, someone can help you figure out how to update it. For example, are you using data binding? Did you write your own code to retrieve the records?

Basically, without seeing your code, I would say you can take whatever it is you are doing in the constructor and put it in a separate method (let's call it `RefreshData`). Then, call `RefreshData` after you delete records from the database.

So, you're creating new controls that represent the data. In that case, there's no mechanism to automatically do the updating work for you, you'll have to code it. You generally have two options:

1. Keep a reference to the controls you created, and remove them from the `Form` before updating it.
2. Implementing something more efficient, like maintain a Dictionary that maps from the Data Rows to the controls that represent it, so that you can go over the updated data, and for each row in your dictionary that disappeared from the data, remove the controls.

You may also want to consider using some control that has a built-in Data Binding mechanism that would save you lots of work. For example, a `GridView`.

Comment: Yes.. sure. I did. This is nothing more concept with code. I am using MSaccess DB with just fetching data from database. My concern is how i will show records with updated after clicking on delete button. I am already mention i am fetching it on when constructor is calling.

Comment: Hello Ran, I got your point. My constructor code is large i can't post it in comment box. I am painting controls with each record on form wondows. I did as your concept. Function is calling after deleted and this re painting but deleted records is seeing on windows. How will i show my construcor code to you ?

Comment: What kind of control are you using to show the data? If it's something like `ListBox` or `ListView`, call `Clear` before updating it. Can you post only the part of the code that paints the data?

Comment: int XL = 164, YL = 25, XB1 = 125, YB1 = 58, XB2 = 180, YB2 = 58, XB3 = 232, YB3 = 58;
         Label[] arr_label = new Label[25];
         Button[] arr_button_send = new Button[25];
         Button[] arr_button_edit = new Button[25];
         Button[] arr_button_delete = new Button[25];arr_button_send[count] = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();                        arr_button_send[count].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(XB1, YB1);arr_button_send[count].AutoSize = 
arr_button_send[count].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(50, 25);  These controls i am using for dynamically attachment.

Answer (score 0):

Could you be looking for Invalidate() ?

Comment: yes i also use this.Invalidate(); But :( not working what i am looking for.

Comment: Are you calling Invalidate on the form? The data structure? The control?

Answer (score 0):

If you are filling the form in constructor you need to extract loading code to a method.
Then call it on DeleteButton.OnClick event after performing delete.